# Combining multiple apps

Tags: angularjs, node.js

If I'm using Nodejs along with Angular to build a website - it seems like its basically a collection of 3 apps so far. To start I have a basic search app (movies) built with Angular and ES, a MEAN based login app and a AngularJS contact form app. How do I combine the 3 apps to make a "website" - if you will. All 3 apps have their own client side routing (UI Router). Now that said, I also have a couple of simple static HTML files that also need to be included in this.

Basically a user would come to the home page (movies app) and search for their favorite movie, actor etc. I want to provide an account feature (login app) so that they can create lists of their favorite movies, actors, scenes etc. How would I combine these 2 apps to form the website?

Do I just combine all 3 apps into 1 big app? Am I missing something?

Comment: If Angular frontends were written with modularity in mind, there should be absolutely no problems with combining them. If they are not, they may be refactored first. This doesn't necessarily apply to backends, the latter can be separate APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depend on what you are going to achieve. Single Page Application has advantages and disadvantages. In your particular case, I would suggest merging this three apps as single one because it has very related entities. Just create single entry point (root module) and include your apps as different modules with a top level routing handle. `UI-router` - is most flexible routing for Ng, so don't miss it. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for a clear, concise answer - and no commentary about what might be a basic question for some, much appreciate!